# json retorna null com caracteres especiais

Tags: php, json, codificação-de-caracteres, htmlentities

Hoje me deparei com esse erro:

Ao tentar codificar um array para json, alguns valores retornam *null*.
Cheguei a solução de antes de utilizar a função **json_encode()** passar todas as strings para UTF-8 com o **htmlentities($string, UTF-8)** porém em um caso especial, uma string possuía esse caractere – (percebam que é diferente de um hífen -), e me retornou erro. olhem os testes que fiz:

```
 $string    = htmlentities('Av. 7 de setembro – Salvador', UTF-8); // String com o caracter que retorna erro
 $string2   = htmlentities('Av. 7 de setembro - Salvador', UTF-8); // String com o Hífen
 $array = array('string' => $string, 'string2' => $string2);
 echo json_encode($array);

 Output: {"string":null,"string2":"Av. 7 de setembro - Salvador"}
```

Existe outra forma de converter esse caractere? Tenho medo que existam outros caracteres que o htmlentities() não resolva.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a constante `ENT_QUOTES` para converter as aspas:

```
 $string    = htmlentities('Av. 7 de setembro – Salvador', ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); // String com o caracter que retorna erro
 $string2   = htmlentities('Av. 7 de setembro - Salvador', ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); // String com o Hífen
 $array = array('string' => $string, 'string2' => $string2);
 echo json_encode($array);
```

**[Exemplo](https://ideone.com/J1OcCc)**

Answer (score 1):

Eu usaria direto o json_encode. Mas se está tendo problemas com caracteres especiais, pode tentar usar as funções:
utf8_encode ou utf8_decode no lugar da htmlentities

Answer (score 0):

Retire o *htmlentities* e use diretamente o [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php):

```
<?php    
  header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  $string    = 'Av. 7 de setembro – Salvador'; // String com o caracter que retorna erro
  $string2   = 'Av. 7 de setembro - Salvador'; // String com o Hífen
  $array = array('string' => $string, 'string2' => $string2);
  echo json_encode($array);
```

*Saida:*

```
{"string":"Av. 7 de setembro \u2013 Salvador","string2":"Av. 7 de setembro - Salvador"}
```

***\u2013:*** [Unicode Character 'EN DASH' (U+2013)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)

***Exemplo:*** [ideone](https://ideone.com/Za4aTY)

Comment: No meu caso, se eu retirar o _htmlentities_ os outros caracteres como çáúàùí... vão retornar NULL

Comment: Ai @DiegoHenrique é a sua página que tem que colocar o cabeçalho correto...

Comment: A aplicação foi desenhada em ISO-8859-1, concordo que utf-8 seria bem melhor de trabalhar! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @DiegoHenrique é só colocar ao codificação então, muitas vezes é feito assim colocando o header na pagina, principalmente quando se trabalha com ajax! no caso é só mudar para ISO-8859-1

Comment: @DiegoHenrique quando for trabalhar com banco vai ser obrigado a usar essa header

Answer (score 0):

Quando eu tenho este tipo de problema eu uso a função "mb_convert_encoding"

```
  mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'LATIN1');
```

Veja o manual da função em
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php