# Existe alguma maneira de se descobrir um erro ocorrido em json_decode?

Tags: php, json

Bem, o PHP tem uma coisa que as vezes considero ruim: Algumas funções lançam `Warning` quando algum erro ocorre, e já outras, retornam `False` ou `Null`.

Um caso que exemplifica isso é o `fopen`.

```
fopen('non-exists.txt', 'r');
```

Gera um `Warning`:

> PHP warning:  fopen(non-exists.txt): failed to open stream: No such file    or directory

Porém existem outros casos que não há nenhum aviso de erro, como no caso das funções `json_decode` e `json_encode`.

Um pequeno exemplo ao tentar decodificar um json mal-formado:

```
 json_decode('{'); // null
```

Eu preciso nesse caso saber que a string `JSON` está mal formada, pois as vezes esse `JSON` vem de fontes externas, e creio que seria interessante enteder porque alguma operação deu erro, e não somente retornar `Null`.

Existe alguma maneira de descobrir qual é o erro ocorrido nessas funções de `Json` do PHP?

Quer dizer, não estou falando de fazer um `if` e saber se tem um erro, mas estou falando de detalhar qual foi o problema ocorrido ao tentar usar a função.

Comment: A resposta que for dada aqui vai ajudar quem teve problema aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21334/json-retorna-null-com-caracteres-especiais?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para detectar um json inválido ou mal formatado use a função `json_last_error_msg()` para obter uma descrição da 'categoria' do problema. Essa função está disponível no php5.5 ou superior.

```
$arr = json_decode('{') or die(json_last_error_msg()); //Syntax error
```

O código acima é apenas um exemplo, o `die()` pode ser trocado por um if.

Em versões anteriores pode-se utilizar exemplo:

```
$arr = json_decode('{') ?: json_last_error();//4 representa o erro de sintaxe.
```

Comment: Ótimo, você deu a resposta certinha... O problema é que, se tiver `json_decode('false')` vai fazer com que o `or` caia no erro..

Comment: +1 cara, valeu..

Comment: Parece que essa função só funciona para versões `5.5>=` do PHP :(

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim, mas tem outra forma de pegar a descrição, através do código de retorno.