# converter dados json para string ou array em php

Tags: php, jquery, json, parser

Tenho este json e gostaria de saber como converter ele para um arrag/string

```
{'texto_mensagem': {'texto': 'Mensagem de envio'}, 'numero_celular': [{'numero': '5537988440956'}, {'numero': '5537988530808'}, {'numero': '5537988555533'}]}
```

Meu cliente é este

```
        $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
             data: "{'texto_mensagem': {'texto': 'Mensagem de envio'}, 'numero_celular': [{'numero': '5537988440956'}, {'numero': '5537988530808'}, {'numero': '5537988555533'}]}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'http://www.e-sms.com.br/api',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (request){
                console.log(request);
            }
        });    
    });
```

Comment: `json_decode()` [seria isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4410/91)?

Comment: Não, ContentType: "application/json"

Comment: json_decode($request->getBody(), true) retorna NULL

Comment: Talvez o json são seja válido, veja: [Existe alguma maneira de se descobrir um erro ocorrido em json_decode?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/125391/91)

Comment: Acreditoq u não se aplique amigo;
O Json é valido.
Porém fala que a sintaxy esta incorreta.

Comment: a questão é que não estou enviando uma atring json e sim um json.

Comment: Seu problema é no php certo? poderia o código?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Tqc4jXpa

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42446/discussion-between-willian-rodrigues-andrade-and-rray).